# Error when trying to start HiveServer2: NullPointerException in ThriftBinaryCLIService

Tags: hive

When I start hiveserver2 with the following command:

```
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

I receive the following error before the program exits:

```
2022-09-12T14:46:53,713 ERROR [Thrift Server] transport.TServerSocket: Could not set socket timeout.
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.net.ServerSocket.setSoTimeout(ServerSocket.java:666) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.listen(TServerSocket.java:117) ~[hive-exec-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer.serve(TThreadPoolServer.java:146) ~[hive-exec-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftBinaryCLIService.run(ThriftBinaryCLIService.java:169) ~[hive-service-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
Hive Session ID = 56c28481-2b0c-4712-808d-ff7ccf31b543
Hive Session ID = 9771e219-095c-4524-b34a-b8e05c335fc0
2022-09-12T14:48:03,871 ERROR [Thrift Server] thrift.ThriftCLIService: Exception caught by ThriftBinaryCLIService. Exiting.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftBinaryCLIService.run(ThriftBinaryCLIService.java:169) ~[hive-service-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
```

Here is a brief explanation of my setup:

- I am using vagrant and VirtualBox to create a "virtual" cluster.
- This is very loosely (since the repository hasn't been updated in a while, I have had to make many changes to get it to work) based on this repository - https://github.com/njvijay/vagrant-jilla-hadoop
- I have created 5 nodes (1 name node and 4 data nodes). The namenode also contains yarnm hive, pig, spark, mysql, python etc.
- I am using Ubuntu 14.04.6, Hadoop 2.10.1, Hive 3.1.3, Spark 3.3.0 and Pig 0.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there may be some compatibility issue between Hadoop 2 and Spark 3. I was able to resolve the error after updating Hadoop, Hive and Spark to the latest versions.